# Is it safe to remove wallpaper registry key?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, group-policy, desktop-customization

Someone forced me a wallpaper using some group policy
After searching the registry database, I found the following on `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\WallpaperStyle` :

[image: http://hpics.li/64b03f3]

However, I didn't know how to find this file
But the main problem: is it safe to delete it ?

Comment: Safe from what? Your IT team yelling at you for doing this? Probably not! Will your PC blow up because of it? Probably not!

Comment: We really cannot for ethical reasons explain how to bypass a group policy.  The wallpaper was set for a reason, valid or not, we really can only suggest you go through the proper channels to change it.

Comment: You definitely won't make friends with your IT department. I'd get with them before changing anything.

Comment: Well I already deleted their firewall, the old antivirus, so much things that one of the guys got surprised when seeing the computer... He took 2 hours to restore them and I'm ready to destroy their policy again xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are running domain environment, for sure it is safe to delete, BUT do you have permission to delete the registry key? Usually you wont have it. Also, group policy will automatic apply again when you log on, so there is no point to delete it.

Comment: When you say permission, do you mean a moral one (permission from the guy who setted this), or an administrative permission ?
I have an administrator account

Comment: well i have one of them ... you know wich one
Thank you for the help, i got rid of the silly wallpaper (the cumputer logs in the network once every 6 months, so will delete when it happens )